# How can a child entity move from one parent to another?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I'm converting an application from my custom ORM to Entity Framework with .Net 4. Things are going pretty well, but I'm unsure how to move a child item to another parent. I'm not sure what pattern I should follow.

With the ORM, I generated methods such as:

```
public void MoveTo_Item(Parent.Row destination)
{
    _inMovement = true;
    _parent_Item.Child_Items.Remove(this);
    parent_id = destination.id;
    destination.Child_Items.Add(this);
    _inMovement = false;
}
```

where:

- `_inMovement == true` prevented `_parent_Item.Child_Items.Remove/Add(this)`
  from triggering a delete/insert in the DB; and
- `parent_id = destination.id` triggered the update in the DB.

The child item itself has child items, so don't think I can just do `parent1.Remove(item)` followed by `parent2.Add(item)`.

How does one properly change the parent item with EF .Net 4?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In EF, if your navigation properties are set up correctly, it should be simply a matter of (made-up names here, obviously)

```
Child child = sourceParent.Children.First();  // or whatever

child.ParentObject = destinationParent;
```

btw, if your custom ORM hit the database *every time* objects were manipulated (which must have been quite resource-intensive, no?), you're going to need to adjust to the EF way of working, where the database isn't hit unless you explicitly say so.

Answer (score 0):

Below is solution for Self Tracking Entities.

Use `ObjectSet.Detach(YourObject)` to detach object from one object set.

There are two functions for attachment. `Attach` should be used if your object is loaded from DB and you expect EF to use Update statement for it. `Attach` is function that you need to use for detached entities.

`AddObject` should be used if you just created your Entity in application and it is not already in DB (`Insert` statement to be used).

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896271.aspx) for more details.